# Pass params of object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to pass the params:

```
private

def purchase_params
  params.require(:purchase).permit(:shop_id, :subscription_id, :created_at)
end
```

With this:

```
@purchases = current_shop.purchases.build(params[:purchase])
@purchases.save!
```

I get all of the params except the subscription_id, it returns nil.
Anybody have any idea what I might be missing here?

Thanks in advance!!

**Update 1**

if I keep it as I initially had it the `<%= current_shop.purchases.inspect %>` 
gives this: Purchase id: 15, subscription_id: nil, shop_id: 14, created_at: "2017-06-13 11:29:43", updated_at: "2017-06-13 11:29:43"

Comment: what does `params.inspect` look like?

Comment: Please post the `params` and also the form

Comment: paste the code of `form`

Comment: `<%= current_shop.purchases.inspect %>` 

gives this <Purchase id: 15, subscription_id: nil, shop_id: 14, created_at: "2017-06-13 11:29:43", updated_at: "2017-06-13 11:29:43">

Comment: please check update 1 for more info

Comment: @Theopap I usually get `param is missing..` error when I have some naming conventions error. For example, I believe in `params.require(:purchase)` you have to user Model name which should be `Purchase` in your case. If it is slightly different, then you have to fix that. Next thing you have to use `purchase_params` as in both answers below suggest. 3rd idea what I can imagine is that there is something wrong with your form which is not basically passing particular values.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to change

```
@purchases = current_shop.purchases.build(params[:purchase])
```

to

```
@purchases = current_shop.purchases.build(purchase_params)
```

And check if you are getting `:subscription_id` inside `purchase` or not. something like this:

```
Parameters: {"purchase"=>{"shop_id"=>"7"}
```

You can check that in rails log

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Deepak Mahakale... I get this error now `param is missing or the value is empty: purchase`

Comment: @Theopap: this error means that you don't have `params[:purchase]`

Comment: @Theopap ok, so it means you are not getting the params in proper format. can you please post whats in params from rails log

Comment: Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"UNVZw04EzzzQOrL+HfAv6jxPxDfzvkU0hgvIUizq8Uaf5mbuBkCi8cqULyhpNi7Lok/V7rONRjPSH8jm5iB7Xg==", "payment_method_nonce"=>"3e75204e-3869-0b1e-6be0-504092780116"}

Comment: Well, you got the reason. You are not getting those params

Comment: I'm also getting this: `SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "purchases" ("shop_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["shop_id", 14], ["created_at", 2017-06-13 14:39:30 UTC], ["updated_at", 2017-06-13 14:39:30 UTC]]`    ... again the subscription_id is missing!!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
@purchases = current_shop.purchases.build(purchase_params)
@purchases.save!
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Rajarshi Das... I"m getting this error now `param is missing or the value is empty: purchase`

Answer (score 0):

I think Ur Trying to store data as relation.
but the forign key can not store.
check your `html.rb` file form. and then pass `subscription_id` as a hidden field